# maas node times out after during juju bootstrap

Tags: server, ssh, juju, maas

I have 6 nodes that have all been commissioned.  I can ssh to 2 of them with ubuntu@ip_address.  The other 4 fail to ssh with

> `Permission denied (publickey)`

Juju deploy fail with

> `Failed to query node's BMC — Node could not be queried node-3c9e137a-744c-11e4-a75c-180373b04ac9 (esxi10.local) connection timeout.`

I have added `ntp` runs during startup and via `cron` via commissioning scripts.  I have even tried adding a second account, complete with password and public keys, but I can't log into these either.

Why would some machines commission correctly and others not?  Any ideas?

Comment: can you separate your script file1, file2, and file3, and explain it in details?

Answer (score 2):

The problem appears to have been caused by the physical clocks being not in sync enough with the server and critical parts of the commissioning happen before they run `ntpdate`.  I installed 3 commissioning files to sync `ntpdate` and the hardware clock.

`01-ntpdate` - syncs with `ntpdate` and then writes to the hardware clock

```
#!/bin/sh<BR>
/usr/sbin/ntpdate -v 143.207.7.23<BR>
/sbin/hwclock -w
```

`01-ntpdate-cron` - installs a `cron` job to sync type every 15 minutes and set the `hwclock`

```
#!/bin/bash    
cat <<EOF >/etc/cron.d/ntpdate
0,15,30,45 * * * * /usr/sbin/ntpdate 143.207.7.23 && /sbin/hwclock -w
EOF
```

`01-S10ntpdate` - installs a boot up script to sync time (and hwclock) on bootup

```
#!/bin/sh -e
cat <<EOF >/etc/init.d/ntpdate

#!/bin/sh -e
/etc/init.d/ntpdate
/usr/sbin/ntpdate -v 143.207.7.23
/sbin/hwclock -w
exit 0
EOF

chmod +rx /etc/init.d/ntpdate
ln -s /etc/init.d/ntpdate /etc/rc2.d/S10ntpdate 
ls -l /etc/init.d/ntpdate /etc/rc2.d/S10ntpdate
exit 0
```

After adding these 3 commissioning files, the first commissioning installs them and actually sets the `hwclock` (and usually fails the commissioning because the fails before it actually sets the time correctly).  The next commissioning runs successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Also, set up a local ntp server, and in /etc/maas/preseeds/preseed-master look for:
d-I      clock-setup/ntp-server    string  ntp.ubuntu.com
and change ntp.ubuntu.com to your ntp server's IP or machine name.